# rendererForOverlay not being called.... after update from MKOverlayView to MKOverlayRenderer

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, renderer, mkoverlay, mkmapviewdelegate

I have a working extention of `MKOverlayView` class with the mapview delegate triggering and executing the – `mapView:viewForOverlay`: delegate method perfectly.  So to move away from a deprecated class, I have changed my extention of `MKOverlayView` to extend `MKOverlayRenderer`... Doing this, but leaving the `viewForOverlay` method in place works fine....

However the delegate method `viewForOverlay` is deprecated as well, so I replace it with the `rendererForOverlay` method to be in alignment with the non Deprecated API and it NEVER gets triggered...

The delegate for the `MapView` is properly hooked up, (which is proven by the `viewForOverlay` working, but when I replace this method with `rendererForOverlay`, which is its replacement, it never ever triggers... and as such my overlay doesn't get drawn. This makes no sense to me.

I am very much at a loss, the only thing different between versions that work, and versions that don't, is this method.  Even after I changed my class from being an `MKOverlayView` extention to an `MKOverlayRenderer` extention the overlay still draws as long as the `viewForOverlay` method exists in the delegate, it gets called. But the moment I replace the `viewForOverlay` delegate method for the `rendererForOverlay` method nada.

Here is the code:

This method works properly whether the class `MapOverlayView` is extending `MKOverlayView` or `MKOverlayRenderer`, either one and this delegate method is called and the overlay is rendered.

```
-(MKOverlayView*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>) overlay{
 MyMapOverlay *mapOverlay = overlay;
 MapOverlayView *mapOverlayView = [[MapOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:mapOverlay];
 return mapOverlayView;
 }
```

For this method I make sure `MapOverlayView` is always extending `MKOverlayRenderer`, but the delegate method NEVER gets triggered.. Why would the above deprecated method always get called and work, but the below proper non deprecated method never get triggered?

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>) overlay{
 MyMapOverlay *mapOverlay = overlay;
 MapOverlayView *mapOverlayView = [[MapOverlayView alloc] initWithOverlay:mapOverlay];
 return mapOverlayView;
 }
```

Comment: it's a lower case 'm' on the method name, mapView:... not MapView:...

Comment: It is lowercase in the code, I transposed it wrong here... I will edit... so problem still exists.

Comment: are you testing on iOS7 simulator/phone?

Comment: One thing you're messing up a bit is the delegate of the MKMapView being an MKOverlayView/Renderer. While the delegate just needs to implement the protocol methods independent of what it is, there is a conceptual difference between an object responsible for returning Views/Renderers and the Views/Renderers themselves, and you're mixing both.

Comment: I am currently testing on simulator.  I appreciate the conceptual difference, but the fact the delegate is not being called is the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the rendererForOverlay method gets called when the Overlay object is within the display map boundaries. You need to scroll the map to where the overlay should be displayed to trigger the call.